# How do I change the default startup directory in Cygwin?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

Whenever I start cygwin, I need to cd several levels
down to the only directory that I care about when using cygwin.

How can I get cygwin to start in this particular directory by
default...i.e., each time I start Cygwin it will be in that directory
already?

I found some things that may be it, or close, but I don't understand them, and there's really no results when I search for these (n00b) terms. Any help would be great!

Comment: Just a little tip: using cygwin you don't need to cd several times - you can do it with one command (suggestions will still appear for subdirectories).

Answer (score 59):

Just add

```
cd /path/to/directory/you/care/about
```

to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: where is that ~/.bashrc file in windows installation

Comment: It depends on how you installed Cygwin, but the Windows path to your Cygwin home directory is usually `C:\cygwin\home\%USERNAME%`, which would make the Windows path to `~/.bashrc` `C:\cygwin\home\%USERNAME%\.bashrc`.

Comment: what if the dafault home directory is a directory where I don't want to put any file.

Comment: @Arturo I think you mess up two things - your user home directory and Cygwin home directory. _.bashrc_ file is anyway there if you install Cygwin.

Comment: currently bashrc file there is in `C:\cygwin64\home\my_user_name` folder

Answer (score 2):

Define "start cygwin"? You can run cygwin servers when you power your machine up, but I'm assuming that's not what you mean.

If you mean, end up in a specific folder every time you open a shell prompt, you can put that in your $HOME/.bashrc

Edit your $HOME/.bashrc using a cygwin editor (one that uses UNIX line endings), add a line

```
cd /whatever/directory/you/want
```

If you're constantly going to this directory, you're probably better off making an alias as well.

In your $HOME/.bashrc put:

```
alias GT='cd /whatever/directory/you/want'
```

Call it whatever you want; I just used GT for "go there", and I uppercase because it makes it easy to separate from builtin commands, which are never capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

in the last line of your .bash_profile (or .profile), put `cd your/dirctory/here`

Answer (score 0):

**python script**

!!before use add .bashrc any string to the end!!

use `name_script.py c:\path`

`path_bachrc` - path to .bashrc

`cmd` - path to cygwin.bat

```python
#***********************************************#
#   gangelXXX@gmail.com                         #
#***********************************************#
import argparse
import subprocess
import os

path_bachrc = 'c:/PP/cygwin/home/adm/.bashrc'
cmd = 'c:\PP\cygwin\Cygwin.bat'

def delEndLineFromFile(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        aList = f.readlines()

    bList = aList[0:-1]

    with open(filename, 'w') as fd:
        fd.writelines(bList)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("newPath", type=str, help="New path in .bachrc cygwin")
args = parser.parse_args();

delEndLineFromFile(path_bachrc);

p = args.newPath;
pNew = 'cd /cygdrive/' + p[:1] + p[2:].replace('\\', '/')
print(pNew)

with open(path_bachrc, 'a') as f:
    f.write(pNew)

PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True)
```

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: python script use name_script.py c:\path\

Comment: path_bachrc - path to .bashrc

Comment: cmd - path to cygwin.bat

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't require editing .bashrc:

Below is a snippet from the official docs on mkpasswd :

> For example, this command:
>
> **Example 3.11. Using an alternate home root**
>
> `$ mkpasswd -l -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd`
>
> would put local users home directories in the Windows 'Profiles' directory.

(answered copied from similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225764/safely-change-home-directory) because I like this solution more that those here)