# Changing default startup directory in CygWin and using alias

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, shell, cygwin

Following this post :
[How do I change the default startup directory in Cygwin?](https://superuser.com/questions/388397/how-do-i-change-the-default-startup-directory-in-cygwin/388410#388410?newreg=d28ed88a398a40a084c792bbc9940354)

I was able to change the default directory by editing the .bashrc file.

I was curious about the alias : I created the same alias GT pointing to the location of a folder I want to work in.
alias as this :

```
 alias GT='cd /whatever/directory/you/want'
```

How do I call the alias in the command prompt to go to this desired directory?

If I try

```
$ GT
-bash: C:/Users/m3/Documents/Education/Python/Lessons: Is a directory
```

```
$ cd GT
-bash: cd: GT: No such file or directory
```

So it doesn't seem to work out this way... I've looked on other threads, I can't seem to find my answer thus far...

Thank you,

Comment: alias is for commands. try `alias GT="cd where_you_want"`

Comment: This is how I defined GT. But then, how do I use it afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the Cygwin Terminal and you have bash as shell.

The following works for me:

```
$ alias GT="cd /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files"
$ GT
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Program File
```

`/cygdrive/c` is the proper way to call the disk `C:`  and if a directory has a space in it, you need to escape it.
Use `Program\ Files`   instead of `Program Files`

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that works. How are we able to know this change, of 'C:/' being actually '/cygdrive/c/'?

Comment: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive